# Loading local JSON file into JS script element

Tags: javascript, html, json, visualization

I am using AnyChart for a Choropleth Map that will show number of users per country.

The template from AnyChart uses the following code to indicate where the data should be pulled from (URL):

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

// load the data
      anychart.data.loadJsonFile("https://static.anychart.com/git-storage/word-press/data/choropleth-map-tutorial/data.json", function (data) {

        // Variables
        // go into the records section of the data
        var geoData = data.records

        // sum of all cases per country
        var sumCases = 0;

        // convert cases and deaths to numbers
        var numC;

        // create a new array with the resulting data
        var data = [];

        // Go through the initial data
        for (var i = 0; i < geoData.length; i++) {
          // convert strings to numbers and save them to new variables
          numC = parseInt(geoData[i].cases);

          // check if we are in the same country by comparing the geoId. 
          // if the country is the same add the cases and deaths to the appropriate variables
          if ((geoData[i + 1]) != null && (geoData[i].geoId == geoData[i + 1].geoId)) {
            sumCases = sumCases + numC;
          }
          else {
            // add last day cases and deaths of the same country
            sumCases = sumCases + numC;

            // insert the resulting data in the array using the AnyChart keywords 
            data.push({ id: geoData[i].geoId, value: sumCases, title: geoData[i].countriesAndTerritories })

            // reset the variables to start over
            sumCases = 0;

          }
        };
```

I want to change this URL to instead pull data from a local JSON file (`users.json`). I replaced the URL with `users.json` (as below) but the map will not render:

```
anychart.data.loadJsonFile("users.json", function (data)
```

I think I need to change `loadJsonFile` to something else but I can't figure out what. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you press F12 and see the dev console, you should see an error message like this,

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'file:///C:/path/to/line-chart.json'
> from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin
> requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
> isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

The ways to work around this,

1. Host your file in a local web server.
2. Upload your file to a public web server.
3. If you really want to get this working locally, try this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) to disable the security policy.